# Proof of cyclic inequity involving radical

Tags: inequality

While learning inequity proof with AM-GM and Cauchy, I made up a few questions for myself. First I proved one I deemed quite straightforward by using common denominator:

$$\frac {a}{b + c} + \frac {b}{a + c} + \frac {c}{a + b} >= \frac{3}{2}$$ where $a,b,c$ are positive real number.

To make it challenging for the sake of exercising, I created

$$ \sqrt{\frac {a}{b + c}} + \sqrt{\frac {b}{a + c}} + \sqrt{\frac {c}{a + b}} >= 3 * \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}$$

which is NOT true (edited after a few replies). The expression should only be $ > 2$. My question is: when radical is involved, is there a general good way to handle it?

Comment: The inequality is wrong. The min value is at $ (a, a, 0)$ which gives  a value of $2$.

Comment: Fine, take $ c \rightarrow 0^+, a = b $, and the value will $\rightarrow 2^+$. So the infimum is 2 (but never achieved).

Comment: You are right, there’s a hole. Just try 1, 1, 1000. I have to add some condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no hard and fast rules to what could work.

Some common approaches are

- Use QM-AM
- Chebyshev
- Holders
- Jensens (but the function isn't convex here)
- Repeated squaring

[IMO 2001/2](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/2001_IMO_Problems/Problem_2) is a worthwhile study of these different approaches.

In this case, the equality doesn't hold when all terms/variables are equal, so there's something else going on, and those approaches I listed are not that likely to work.

---

WLOG, we may normalize to $ a+b+c = 1$.

Then, we want to study the behavior of $ f(x) = \sqrt{ \frac{x}{ 1-x}}$ on $ 0 \leq x \leq 1$, and want to bound $ \sum f(a) $ from below.

**Claim:** $f(x) \geq 2x$ with equality at $ x = 0, \frac{1}{2}$.

This can be proven directly by squaring and expanding, since $\frac{1}{4} \geq x (1-x)$.

To motivate coming up with this inequality (instead of magic), I used the tangent line method.

**Corollary:** Hence $ \sum f(a) \geq 2 \sum a = 2$, with equality at $ ( 0, \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2})$ and permutations.

Note: Since we require $a,b,c$ to be positive, hence we have $\sum f(a) > 2$.